# Possible to map an image onto another so that the new one is the same size and shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

I'm a bit of a newbie when confronted with photoshop and Fireworks etc, I much prefer drawing mountains in paint.

However, I've a wonderful idea for a site navigation element but I'm having difficulties.

I have the original image and an image the size and shape of a jigsaw piece.

I need to make the original image the same size and shape as the jigsaw piece image so that I can map the coordinates onto it for the html markup.

Is this possible and if so could someone give me an idiots guide as to how I might achieve it please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, both photoshop and fireworks allow you to resize an image to match the size of another. Use the transform tool/feature.

Answer (score 1):

Anything for the web will be rectangular, so your puzzle shape should be a png (or svg) with transparency. Set up a photoshop file with a mask and export your image variations from there.

Comment: I'm using an image map so the clickable area within the image itself won't be rectangular.  It's a really cool feature, combined with jQuery and it's amazing :)
It's the "setting up a mask" etc that throws me.